# Run Win7 Guest (raw disk) in Ubuntu (which was installed as Dual Boot on existing Win7)

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on top of Win 7 as a dual boot (awesome!).  I'm hoping to use VirtualBox to run my original Win7 instance as a guest OS under Ubuntu.  I found [this existing question](https://serverfault.com/questions/241678/booting-a-native-windows-install-in-virtualbox-is-it-possible) and followed the directions to no avail.

I can get the VMDK file created but when I run it I just get a blank black screen with no additional information and Windows never loads.  I see no HD activity or anything that would indicate it's loading.

I used this command to create the VMDK file:

```
VBoxManager internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename ~/.VirtualBox/Win7Native.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda3
```

It looks like everything was created correctly but I just get a blank screen when I run the VM.

I do get this warning when I boot the VM:

> **VirtualBox - Warning**
>
> The virtual machine execution may run into and error condition as
>   described below...
>
> The medium '/home/XXX/.VirtualBox/Win7Native.vmdk' has a logical size
>   of 583GB but the file system the medium is located on can only handle
>   up to 16GB in theory.
>
> We strongly recommend to put all your virtual disk images and the
>   snapshot folder on a proper file system (e.g. etc3) with a sufficient
>   size.
>
> ErrorId: Fat Partition Detected Severity: Warning

How can I get this working?

Comment: try running `gksudo virtualbox` to start virtualbox; I tried this a while ago and (if I remember correctly) virtualbox needs to run as root to be able to read and write from the partition

Comment: Thanks but that's not the issue in this case.  I did as you suggested but still get a blank screen.

Comment: try running with `gksudo virtualbox --debug-command-line` to get some activity logs up

Comment: did that, something prints but then a bunch of buffer: -- statements print and fill the buffer

Comment: It could be a Windows problem to me. A sudden change of hardware (like moving from real to virtualized one) usually breaks Windows. You can avoid it by using Hardware profiles in Windows, but I don't know exactly how they work.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I've gotten past this but it has been a journey.  I'm not 100% yet -- getting a BSOD when booting into windows but I have some ideas for that I will try this week.  I will post an answer with reference websites and instructions when I'm done.